# Android google map Api sha1 and package is error

Tags: android-maps-v2, api-key

API_KEY I tried but sha-1;my package is not accepted

Error is [Your input was invalid].

This is my sha-1 
[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBxxa0zIyuP2OJXldb-FUoGSSDcfbryVbA"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got Sha1 and packege

I got Api key